# Search not indexing groups of URLs

Tags: bug, search

There are a couple of images used on Ask Ubuntu a lot (namely `bit.ly/software-[large, small]` and `hostmar.co/software-[large, small]`).  All of the bit.ly images are outdated and need to be updated to the hostmar.co links, however when I search using

```
url:bit.ly/software-large
```

or

```
url:bit.ly/software-small
```

it returns nothing. This is contradicted by [a data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/639136/broken-software-centre-links-in-ask-ubuntu) clearly showing more of these links (280 rows - minus some the community has fixed since the last dump).

This seems to be a bug of some sort with search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a silly bug in the indexing code, it only picked up URLs from links, but not images. I've [heard some rumors](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35974192#35974192) about Regex parsing HTML...

Anyway, after the HTTPS rewrite, the posts received a new timestamp and were picked up by the incremental indexing process: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhostmar.co